# ngx-translate: Load JSON from Angular 6 library

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am building Angular 6 application with 3 libraries ...

I would like to have 3 json files containing translations in each of them.

Is it possible to have TranslateLoader that reads those files from installed libraries. So that I could say something like

```
new TranslateLibraryLoader(http, ["@company/lib1", "@company/lib2", 
"@company/lib3", "./assets/i18n/"]
```

Comment: Not sure about the loader doing this but you can in the angular cli configure it to move all the company lib jsons to assets folders

Answer (score 2):

ngx-translate needs the files from the libraries at runtime. So first you have to tell angular to integrate these files in your build. In your `angular.json` do:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "input": "./path-to-company/lib1/translations.json",
    "bundleName": "translations.lib1.json",
    "lazy": true
  },
  // repeat for all libs
],
```

Then you can configure a [TranslateHttpLoader](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) to load these files or [implement your own one](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#api):

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, yourPath, yourSuffix);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The cli complains about a wrong schema, and that it expects a string inside the "assets" array. Using just the string, which in my case should be `dist/lib1/assets`, the cli complains that "asset path must start with the project source root". And no, using "src/../dist/lib1/assets" does not do the trick...